# How to create tag's dynamically as receiving a response from the server?

Tags: javascript

I'm work with **google-analytics api**

Code that I use taken from  [**here**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js) only changed the client ID.

When I request a google server, it returns to me a JSON file at the bottom.

```
{
  "kind": "analytics#gaData",
  "id": "in here my ID",
  "query": {
    "start-date": "30daysAgo", //monthly statistic
    "end-date": "today", //last day today
    "ids": "ga:172427234",
    "dimensions": "ga:country", //regions
    "metrics": [
      "ga:users" //users
    ],
    "start-index": 1,
    "max-results": 1000
  },
  "itemsPerPage": 1000,
  "totalResults": 7,
  "selfLink": "there some link",
  "profileInfo": {
    "profileId": "172427234",
    "accountId": "116539423",
    "webPropertyId": "UA-116539423-1",
    "internalWebPropertyId": "172991088",
    "profileName": "any info for website",
    "tableId": "ga:172427234"
  },
  "containsSampledData": false,
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "ga:country",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:users",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:users": "43523" //all users count which were in site
  },
  "rows": [ // regions from which they came to the site and how much user-entered from each region
    [
      "Dubai",
      "28961"
    ],
    [
      "Germany",
      "1400"
    ],
    [
      "Netherlands",
      "111"
    ],
    [
      "Poland",
      "10"
    ],
    [
      "Russia",
      "1021"
    ],
    [
      "Ukraine",
      "28"
    ],
    [
      "United States",
      "11992"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And the problem is that as you can see there are countries and how many users came from each country

I need to create a tag dynamically as I receive a response from the server.The country can be 10 or 100 or 1000, so I need to create tags dynamically as data is received. I use this code in the bottom but the problem is that it show only first country and users.(it work's once) **Dubai, 28961**

After first country console show's an error`Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

And by the way, this code works  (shows Germany, 1400)

```
document.querySelector(".numb").innerHTML = country[1];
```

But I can not use it since it is not dynamic. I just can not duplicate it and change the value supplied in the variable country

I provided the piece of code that I changed from `queryCoreReportingApi` function from the link at the top

```
.then(function(response) {
    let users = JSON.parse(response.result.totalsForAllResults["ga:users"]);
    var country = response.result.rows;
    var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
    console.log(country.length);
     while (country.length > 0) {
          for(let i = 0;i < country.length;i++){
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.className = "country-users";
              document.querySelector('.google-text-block').appendChild(span);
              document.querySelector('.google-text-block').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              for (let j = 0; j < country.length; j++) {

              let countryUsers = document.querySelectorAll(".country-users");
              countryUsers[j].innerHTML = country[i];

            }
          }
        }
```

And little bit HTML which I change from google file

```
<div class="google-text-block">
      <span class="users-numb">Users:</span>
      <span class="numb"></span>
  </div>
```

Please anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, this is how you should do it.

No need for inside `for` loop.

```js
var info = [
    [
      "Dubai",
      "28961"
    ],
    [
      "Germany",
      "1400"
    ],
    [
      "Netherlands",
      "111"
    ],
    [
      "Poland",
      "10"
    ],
    [
      "Russia",
      "1021"
    ],
    [
      "Ukraine",
      "28"
    ],
    [
      "United States",
      "11992"
    ]
  ];
  
  
  
  var country = info;
          for(let i = 0;i < country.length;i++){
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.className = "country-users";
              document.querySelector('.google-text-block').appendChild(span);
              document.querySelector('.google-text-block').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

             span.innerHTML = country[i];
          }
```

```html
<div class="google-text-block">
      <span class="users-numb">Users:</span>
      <br>
      <span class="numb"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) +1 from me

Comment: @Spectr I have updated answer with your code and what was wrong with your code.